# error: fatal error: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found: Installing scala 2.11.8 under ubuntu 17.10:

Tags: scala, ubuntu

I am trying to install scala under ubuntu 17.10:

```
$ scala -version     
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

I have installed the jdk version 8:

```
$ java -version  
openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-8u144-b01-2-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

I can compile and run a scala program if I do it in two steps:

```
$ scalac rip.scala

$ scala rip
hello world
```

But I cannot compile and run in one invocation of scala:

```
$ scala rip.scala
error: fatal error: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
one error found
```

I can't figure what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing. I would appreciate any help.